# Any way to track the CPU usage and memory usage for an executable

Tags: performance, memory, cpu-usage

I want to see the resources an executable uses when I run it from a command prompt/powershell.

Ideally it would be great to have a tool that does something like this straight from the command prompt:

```
./myexecutable -arg1 -arg2 --trackperformance
cpu usage: 12%
memory usage: 1MB
```

I did read stuff about performance monitor but it doesn't seem to be able to track what I want (cpu usage, memory usage overall for the specific executable that I will run).

Any ideas of a tool or command built into the command line that does this?

Comment: You're looking for something that already exists; that is either (a) about usage of built-in commands or (b) a software recommendation request.  Either way it is not a programming question.

Comment: Well I'd argue it is. How are you supposed to write more efficient code if you don't know your changes are having a positive affect? It seems like such a basic functionality that doesn't seem to be asked about/doesn't have a simple solution. Nevertheless I have also posted a question on 'software recommendations'